# wp_enqueue_script vs. wp_register_script

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

Trying to do the right thing here, and tying myself in a knot! So, in my header.php before `wp_admin`, I have:

```
wp_enqueue_script('commonfunctions', child_template_directory . '/script/commonfunctions.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-draggable'), '1.0', true);
```

which works. Basically, I have a custom js file which needs jquery and jqueryui as dependencies. I since took 'jquery' out as it seems to be loaded twice irrespectively. I also had a function hooked into 'init' in functions.php, but that didn't seem to have any advantage?

I want to include the validate script from CDN as this will also be a dependency of my custom script. I thought I would register the script like so:

```
wp_register_script('validate', 'http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.min.js', true);
```

and then add 'validate' to the dependencies array in enqueue, like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script('commonfunctions', child_template_directory . '/script/commonfunctions.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-draggable', 'validate'), '1.0', true);
```

in that order, as jquery is also a dependency of validate. Phew! That doesn't work, I'm obviously misunderstanding something - please help me uncurl what I'm trying to do here...

Answer (score 2):

I think you should just enqueue the script as well (for your validate script). I would wrap it around one whole function as well to avoid issue [#11526](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11526): calling out

Thus all together:

```
<head>
...
<?php 

function mytheme_enqueue_script() {
// Load jQuery
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
// Load draggable
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-draggable');
//load your script
wp_enqueue_script('commonfunctions', child_template_directory . '/script/commonfunctions.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-draggable'), '1.0', true);
// Load validate
wp_enqueue_script('validate','http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.min.js', array('jquery'), true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'mytheme_enqueue_script');
```

Sorry, i haven't tested this yet. So i may be off.

Comment: jQuery should already be a dependancy for `jquery-ui-draggable`, so you can probably remove the enqueue for jQuery as it's likely unnecessary. Again, if `commonfunctions` has draggable as a dependacy, you don't need to enqueue it(that's the point of dependancies).

Answer (score 1):

> I since took 'jquery' out as it seems to be loaded twice irrespectively.

This should not happen and is likely cause by some other (poor) code active.

You have wrong `true` in `validate` registration - after source comes dependencies array and `true` is meaningless there.

Otherwise this seems fine in general. Works from quick test. Could you describe more precisely what exactly and how "doesn't work"?

Comment: Ah yes, I spotted that. Presumably, it can take null as an argument?

Comment: It may have been all that was wrong. I now have:
`wp_register_script('validate', 'http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
  wp_enqueue_script('commonfunctions', child_template_directory . '/script/commonfunctions.js', array('jquery-ui-draggable', 'validate'), '1.0', true);` and that works as long as I place it in the footer, not the header