# Scripts not loading through function Method in Wordpress Theme

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I am trying to load CSS and Javscripts through the functions. CSS are loading, but dont know what mistake has been done that javascripts and Jquery are not loading through the functions method.

I tried by directly loading scripts through the head section and it worked, but by functions method it is not loading. I am producing the excerpts of the code here →

```
  /* Register scripts. */
        wp_register_script( 'custom', JS . '/jquery-3.1.1.js');
                wp_register_script( 'custom', JS . '/custom.js');
```

Do you think that there is any mistake commited in this also →

```
/*-------------------------------------------*/
/* 1. CONSTANTS */
/*-------------------------------------------*/
define( 'THEMEROOT', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
define( 'IMAGES', THEMEROOT . '/img' );
define( 'JS', THEMEROOT . '/js' );
```

The live WP site link can be found [here](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/) for any direct troubleshooting.

Try to click the hamburger menu and then the scripts will not load thats why the hamburger menu is not animating.

**The Complete Function →**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'klogeto_scripts' ) ) {
function klogeto_scripts() {
    /* Register scripts. */
    // wp_register_script( 'jquery', JS . '/jquery-3.1.1.js');
            // wp_register_script( 'custom', JS . '/custom.js',  array(), '20151215', true);
            // wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );
            wp_register_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/custom.js', array(), '20151215', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js' );


    /* Load the stylesheets. */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', THEMEROOT . '/css/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', THEMEROOT . '/css/responsive.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','klogeto_scripts');
```

}

Comment: Don't register your own version of jQuery, use the one that is included with WordPress.

Comment: that is not just the issue, but the custom.js is also not loading. Any Clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several fundamental problems with what you're trying to do that prevent you reaching your goal

### The Problems

#### Naming

You register 2 scripts, but you name them both 'custom'. How is WordPress supposed to know which script you meant when you later tell it to display 'custom'?

```
/* Register scripts. */
wp_register_script( 'custom', JS . '/jquery-3.1.1.js');

// does this overwrite the previous line? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
wp_register_script( 'custom', JS . '/custom.js');
```

So lets fix that by giving them different names ( and proper indenting ):

```
/* Register scripts. */
wp_register_script( 'wpnovice-jquery', JS . '/jquery-3.1.1.js');
wp_register_script( 'wpnovice-custom', JS . '/custom.js');
```

Notice that I prefixed each, `custom` is a super generic term, and it's possible it's being used already.

#### WP Already Comes With JQuery!

Never bundle a library that already comes with WordPress. Doing what you did could lead to multiple copies and versions of jQuery being present on the frontend. Instead, tell WP that jQuery is required for your script:

```
/* Register scripts. */
wp_register_script( 'wpnovice-custom', JS . '/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

#### Registration != Enqueing

Registering your script tells WordPress they exist, but not what to do with them. WordPress already registers a lot of scripts, yet these don't appear on the frontend of every WordPress site.

It's the difference between teaching somebody how to build a house, and somebody actually building that house.

So, after registering, you need to call `wp_enqueue_script` to tell WordPress how to add that script to your page

```
/* Register scripts. */
wp_register_script( 'wpnovice-custom', JS . '/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpnovice-custom' );
```

#### Timing

Even with the newest version of that code, it may not work! This is because timing and location are important. In the same way that asking for your steak medium rare after it's been cooked doesn't work, asking WP to print scripts when it's already done the script printing won't work either.

As a general piece of advice, don't put code in the global scope sitting in a file, instead wrap it in an action or hook, so that it runs when it's supposed to ( and can be unhooked when needed ).

Here we want the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook/action. Here's an example taken from the Core WP docs:

```
function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'filename.js', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script' );
```

#### A Final Note on Constants

```
/*-------------------------------------------*/
/* 1. CONSTANTS */
/*-------------------------------------------*/
define( 'THEMEROOT', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
define( 'IMAGES', THEMEROOT . '/img' );
define( 'JS', THEMEROOT . '/js' );
```

I would advise against these, they're super generic names, and pollute the global namespace. In this case they may be misleading or cause problems.

This version of the register script call, is explicit, and there's no ambiguity about wether it references the correct URL or not:

```
// register script
wp_register_script( 'wpnovice-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Comment: I've removed my answer as this is MUCH more complete. I will endeavour to write answers like this in the future. Very nice breakdown.

Comment: I am a beginner, and it is slightly too much for me in its entirety to understand. I have one question sir. Do you want to say that ing should be done in some other functions and enequing should be done in some other functions?

Comment: @Frits there's no upvotes for effort if you delete your answers, and you can always make edits and improvements :)

Comment: @TheWPNovice you can do them in separate functions if you want to, I do mine in the same function, that parts entirely up to you. There are a lot of resources out there on how to enqueue scripts read around for more examples. I would put a full example of your code in the answer, but nobody would learn anything if they could just copy paste, and all the code you need is already there, just a trivial 1 line re-arrangement required

Comment: I think I have done everything accoridng to your instructions, but still custom.js is not loading → https://www.screencast.com/t/PAYsaLJcI

Comment: @TheWPNovice where is that code located? Is that functions.php? Do the stylesheets load? Is there anything in your browsers dev tools console? Does the script include appear in the view source region with the correct URL? Have you turned off caching plugins to make sure they aren't interfering?

Comment: Sir,  That code is located in theme's functions.php. 2. Yes, the stylesheets are loading flawlessly. 3. there is not a single plugin active sir. even I have deactivated the default plugins that are activated when we freshly install a wordpress. I slightly modified the custom.js [Click Here](https://www.screencast.com/t/bj4nQFmZ)  The live link where the theme is working is [this](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/) This is the full function that is reegistering and enqueing the scripts.[Click Here](https://www.screencast.com/t/47CViP3uxhy)

Comment: custom.js seems to be loading, but not working. [click here](https://www.screencast.com/t/vakeoXrBODzw)

Comment: That's because you have a javascript error, in `custom.js`, you tried to use `$` but jQuery is already in no conflict mode. Your question asked how to get the script to load, and you've succeeded, can you mark this as the answer? If you're still having trouble with the javascript inside `custom.js`, ask on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

Once you register your script, you need to enqueue it.

The below assumes you are using a theme:

```
wp_register_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array(), '20151215', true ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js' );
```

I would also suggest using WordPress's built-in jQuery file.

**EDIT**

The complete function should look like this:

```
function my_custom_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array(), '20151215', true ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts' );
```

Comment: I did what you said, but the problem doesnt seems to be fixed → https://www.screencast.com/t/hFr0noN8Ldqd

Comment: is this inside a plugin or a theme?

Comment: Inside a theme.

Comment: Cool - I've adjusted my answer. I think your problem is with `'custom', JS . '` that "JS" doesn't mean anything in this regard.

Comment: upgraded, still doesnt work → https://www.screencast.com/t/6UzrwTQP

Comment: Where in your theme is the .js file located? (i.e. is it in a folder labelled scripts or something like that?)

Comment: In the themes js folder.

Comment: Then change `get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.js'` to `get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/custom.js'`

Comment: Already done. Please check this → [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/uB1WcZ5WDl) I have uploaded the complete function in the main question.

Comment: :( this answer has copy pasta

Comment: also no need to delete the question, that's potential upvotes for yourself, as well as info from the OP that's no longer available ( yay for mod powers )

Answer (score 0):

First your site has some js error. You can see your site in chrome console tab and see there is an error like Uncaught

```
TypeError: $ is not a function at custom.js:1
```

Regarding adding the js in your site you have done like

```
wp_register_script( 'custom', JS . '/jquery-3.1.1.js');
wp_register_script( 'custom', JS . '/custom.js');
```

Its totally wrong. You don't need to add external jQuery in wordpress. Wordpress has already that file.

**Where is wp_enqueue_script?**

wp_enqueue_script and wp_register_script is different. Please go through these below link to know about them

https://jhtechservices.com/wordpress-wp_enqueue_script-vs-wp_register_script/

[https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/
when-should-i-use-wp-register-script-with-wp-enqueue-script-vs-just-wp-enque](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82490/%20when-should-i-use-wp-register-script-with-wp-enqueue-script-vs-just-wp-enque)

[wp_enqueue_script vs. wp_register_script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/wp-enqueue-script-vs-wp-register-script)

You should do like this

```
wp_register_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array(jquery), '1.0', true ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js' );
```